# spring 3 tiles reload body - keep header and menu static

Tags: spring, static, load, fragment, tiles

I'm using spring 3 with Tiles 2. I have separated body, header and menu. What i would like to achieve is that when user clicks on the options in the menu, only the body is reloaded; keeping the menu and header static. Any hints how can this be done? I have tried already with Spring.addDecoration

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.AjaxEventDecoration({
   elementId: "countryMenu",
   formId: "countryMenuForm",
   event: "onclick",
   params: {fragments: "body"}
}));
</script>
```

but didn't work well

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem we are working on at FINN.no
That is we would like the composite pattern (that Tiles gives) to work both server-side and client-side.

Today we take a simple approach where, given the definition and attribute name, we fetch the template for this attribute and render it again client-side. We use mustache templates for this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "template/{definitionName}/{attributeName:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public static void fetchTemplateDefinition(
        @PathVariable("definitionName") String definitionName,
        @PathVariable("attributeName") String attributeName,
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {


    ApplicationContext tilesContext = ServletUtil.getApplicationContext(httpRequest.getSession().getServletContext());
    TilesContainer tilesContainer = getTilesContainer(tilesContext);
    ServletRequest servletRequest = new ServletRequest(tilesContext, httpRequest, httpResponse);
    String templatePath = getTemplatePath(tilesContext, definitionName, attributeName, tilesContainer, servletRequest);
    InputStream templateStream = loadResourceInputStream(templatePath, tilesContext);
    IOUtils.copy(templateStream, httpResponse.getOutputStream());
}
```

Spring.addDecoration(..) looks interesting! i'll need to read more into that…